# Best way to fade in/out image

Tags: c#, image, c#-3.0, c#-4.0, fade

What is the best (least resource heavy) way to fade an image in and out every 20 seconds with a duration of 1 second, against a black background (screensaver), in C# ?

(an image about 350x130px).

I need this for a simple screensaver that's going to run on some low level computers (xp).

Right now I'm using this method against a pictureBox, but it is too slow:

```
    private Image Lighter(Image imgLight, int level, int nRed, int nGreen, int nBlue)
    {
        Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(imgLight);
        int conversion = (5 * (level - 50));
        Pen pLight = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(conversion, nRed,
                             nGreen, nBlue), imgLight.Width * 2);
        graphics.DrawLine(pLight, -1, -1, imgLight.Width, imgLight.Height);
        graphics.Save();
        graphics.Dispose();
        return imgLight;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could probably use a Color Matrix like in this example on msdn

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w177ax15%28VS.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a Pen and the DrawLine() method, you can use [Bitmap.LockBits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits) to access the memory of your image directly.  Here's a [good explanation](https://web.archive.org/web/20121203144033/http://www.bobpowell.net/lockingbits.htm) of how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Put a Timer on your form, and in the constructor, or the Form_Load,
write

```
    timr.Interval = //whatever interval you want it to fire at;
    timr.Tick += FadeInAndOut;
    timr.Start();
```

Add a private method

```
private void FadeInAndOut(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Opacity -= .01; 
    timr.Enabled = true;
    if (Opacity < .05) Opacity = 1.00;
}
```

Comment: You should ideally use two timers. One would be set to 20 seconds, and would trigger a fade by starting the second timer. The second timer would be set to a small time (e.g. 0.1s) and would increment/decrement opacity until the fade is finished and then would Stop() itself. THat way, you don't have a high-frequency timer running continuously. Note that Forms timers are notoriously unreliable, so you may not get a very smooth fade using them - but for what you want they'll probably be ok most of the time.

Comment: Interesting,  but how is two timers, one of which is running more ore less continuously at high frequency, better than a single timer at the same high frequency ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on this

```
    private void animateImageOpacity(PictureBox control)
    {
        for(float i = 0F; i< 1F; i+=.10F)
        {
            control.Image = ChangeOpacity(itemIcon[selected], i);
            Thread.Sleep(40);
        }
    }

    public static Bitmap ChangeOpacity(Image img, float opacityvalue)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height); // Determining Width and Height of Source Image
        Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        ColorMatrix colormatrix = new ColorMatrix {Matrix33 = opacityvalue};
        ImageAttributes imgAttribute = new ImageAttributes();
        imgAttribute.SetColorMatrix(colormatrix, ColorMatrixFlag.Default, ColorAdjustType.Bitmap);
        graphics.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), 0, 0, img.Width, img.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, imgAttribute);
        graphics.Dispose();   // Releasing all resource used by graphics 
        return bmp;
    }
```

It's also recommended to create another thread because this will freeze your main one.