# Change transparency of images

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transparency

I hope you are having a nice day!

In my game I have some images and I want to change their transparency through time (like 5 seconds until they become completely visible).
I found a way to kinda do it for sprite renderers by pressing keys but not for images and I want to execute it automatically.
So not sth like `GameObject.setActive(true/false)` but really over time.

I hope someone of you can help me out :)

Warm regards

Comment: Could this one be of help perhaps (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829339/best-way-to-fade-in-out-image)? When you say image, do you mean a PictureBox/BitMap or?

Comment: `var color = image.material.color; color.a = 0.5f; image.material.color = color;` ?

Comment: What is your exact question: How do I set the alpha of an `Image`? How to I change a value over time? ... or something else?

Comment: @Toby_TheBlock by `Image` I would guess OP rather refers to [`UnityEngine.UI.Image`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Image.html) (hence the `unity3d` tag) ;)

Comment: @derHugo Ups, missed that one :P

Comment: @Toby_TheBlock Well it is an empty object I put an image into :D

Comment: @derHugo Lets say I hava picture which exists. When I run the game it is invisible but after 5 seconds it gets visible over time. So from second to second the picture becomes clearer

Comment: @Big_F Yes, I understood what you want to achieve ... but what exactly do you have an issue with? What have you tried? There are already questions and answers here like e.g. [How to fade in UI.Image in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56516299/how-to-fade-in-ui-image-in-unity) which probably covers your question ...

Comment: @derHugo yes I saw that question and added it to my image (it has the function of a button) but nothing happens when I change the value of the fade. The questions here are all about colors and not the image itself. That is what I am struggling with :D

Answer (score 0):

For Unity, you have to actually fade the color over time in Update(). But you can use Coroutine to fade image using alpha of color. It will be cost effective for your app.

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Fade : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Image image;

    //visible or invisible
    public float target = 0.0f;

    public float second = 2.0f;

    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(FadeImage((getImageDone) =>
        {
            if (getImageDone) 
            {
                //code after Fade visible 
            }
        }));
    }

    private IEnumerator FadeImage(Action<bool> action)
    {
        var alpha = image.color.a;
        for (var t = 0.0f; t < 1.0f; t += Time.deltaTime / second)
        {
            //change color as you want
            var newColor = new Color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, Mathf.Lerp(alpha, target , t));
            image.color = newColor;
            yield return null;
            action(image.color.a < 0.05f);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
The code seems like it applies to the colors of the image but in my case I am referring to the whole image itself which has several colors. Or am I understanding sth not right? 

Comment: I applied it to my stuff and it does it vice versa :D
I need it to fade in after some seconds and I don't know which part has to be changed.  How can that be done? I am not really able to read the code e.g. how you set the time until it is invisible. Does Time.deltaTime / 2.0f stand for 2 seconds? :D
I mean, I could mess around and change values or <s but I really wanna understand what is going on there
Also, is that appliable for texts?

Comment: Don't double implement the same method ;) rather have one routine and decide the start and end value depending on given parameter

Comment: I have changed code and after recommendation of @derHugo, I have merged two function. You can control speed of fade changing value of second.

Comment: @Big_F It will change alpha value of whole image, you can read docs of Unity about how Image component work, it will be more helpful.

Comment: @Nobi It still does it the other way round. First the image is visible but then it becomes invisible :D
Which values have to be changed?
And how can it be applied to a text?

Comment: @Nobi Also I don't get what happens in StartCoroutine. You are refering to a method but it is not in the code :D

Answer (score 0):

Well You Can Always use `Image.CanvasRenderer.setAlpha` method along with `Mathf.lerp` or you can use `Image.crossFadeAlpha` directly it does what it's name suggests...